# How to make it faster?

Tags: python, excel

So the code that I wrote in python works perfectly fine. I tested it out on smaller files. Now its ready for the two big files they want me to process with it. The code loads in two excel files, takes the strings that I named "Matching String", and performs a fuzzy look up between the two, and pushes the result into excel file.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

# File Path
filename = r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\AddressTest4.xlsx"
filename1 = r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\CertsExcel.xlsx"

# Load Excel File
companyA = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name = "Address String Match")
companyB = pd.read_excel(filename1, sheet_name = "ExtractExcelFiles")


# Customer lists
A = [customer for customer in companyA["Matching String"]]
B = [customer for customer in companyB["Matching String"]]

tuples_list = [max([(fuzz.token_set_ratio(i.lower(),j.lower()),j) for j in A]) for i in B]

similarity_score, fuzzy_match = map(list,zip(*tuples_list))



# Create pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({"Original Name": B, "Matching Name": fuzzy_match, "similarity score":similarity_score})

# Export to Excel
df.to_excel(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Fuzz Test3.xlsx", sheet_name="Fuzzy Match3", index=False)
```

The files that I did tests on only had about 30 entries in them. So when I ran the these test files it took like a minute to process. While this one has 3688 entries and the other one has 26959 entries. Its been running for about 5 mins now, and I'm just now realizing this might take longer than I thought. Anyone have tips on how to make this run faster or should I split up these files, into smaller ones and just run several at the same time?

Comment: Where is the bottleneck?

Comment: With 30 rows in each, you're doing about 1,000 fuzzy matches.  With 3688 and 26959 rows, you will be doing 100 million fuzzy matches.  Fuzzy matches are not quick.  If 1,000 take a minute, then 100 million will take about 2 months.  You need to find a different way to do what you are doing.

Comment: @PaulH The processing time for fuzzy lookup. I believe that is taking up the most time. Since its taking one string from one excel and comparing it to all of them in the second one.

Comment: Consider using rapidfuzz or jellyfish.

Comment: You might look at Soundex or Metaphone.  You transform each list into an "encoded" form, then look for exact matches.

Comment: @TimRoberts That the issue with information that I have I can't make a direct comparison, or else I would have have just done xlookup between the two. I think best bet is just to split up the larger one into 5 files and just run 5 versions of this at the same and stitch them back together.

Comment: @NadirBelhaj Never heard of those but look into it, thank you.

Comment: What algorithms like Soundex do is replace each name with an encoded value, so that common omissions and misspellings produce the same value.  It's a great way for handling names that might be misspelled.

Comment: @TimRoberts Oh that's interesting, I'll give it shot I have till Friday to get something upload. Thank you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.